# Display inputs from multiple text boxes via Jquery array

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the inputs from all of the input boxes. Then add to an array and printing this via a `<p>` class.

The trigger should be a button that then starts a for loop across all the input classes. Am I missing something simple?

**HTML**

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>

</div>
<p class="result"></p>
<button id="add">SUMBIT
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class="encdom_local" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
$("button#add").click(function() {
    var encdom_local = [];
    $('.encdom_local').each(function() {
        values.push(encdom_local.val()+',');
    });
    $(".result").html(encdom_local.join(""));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/16740/

Comment: `values.push(` I dont see the variable `values` declared anywhere

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa is correct. If you look at the JS console on your fiddle. It throws an error that values is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

You should get value of input (not array) and then push to the array you created above. Then use join with coma separator instead of pushing val() + ","

```
$("button#add").click(function() {
    var encdom_local = [];
    $('.encdom_local').each(function() {
        encdom_local.push($(this).val());
    });
    $(".result").html(encdom_local.join(","));
});
```